# How can I install a build tool using create file in github actions

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I need to install Seihon (https://github.com/ldez/seihon) for github actions:

```
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Install
  run: curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ldez/seihon/master/godownloader.sh | bash -s -- -b $GOPATH/bin v0.5.1
- name: Build
  run: make publish-images
```

Unfortunately that fails:

```
install: cannot create regular file '/bin/seihon': Permission denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

What do I need to do on github actions to install a build tool?

Comment: Try to use `sudo`?

Comment: I was so fixed on TracisCI not needing sudo anymore. That worked, thank you!